# ValueError at /cart/remove/ could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, django

This code is showing me an error.

```
def removeFromCart(request):
request.session.set_expiry(0)
obj_to_remove = int(float(request.POST['obj_id']))
obj_index = request.session['cart'].index(obj_to_remove)
request.seession['cart'].pop(obj_index)
return redirect('cart')
```

Comment: Likely the `obj_id` is the *empty* string, hence it can not convert it to a float.

Comment: How did you make the HTTP request in the first place, how does the form look like?

Comment: <form action="remove/" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="hidden" name='obj_id' 
                    value={{item_id}}>
                    <button>
                    <i class="fa fa-remove"></i> </button>
                </form>

Comment: Are you sure you did pass an `item_id` to the template? Likely there simply is no such template variable.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. item_id was wrong. inside a loop, it should have been an item.id